# generaly disable warnings and messagers in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a way how to generally dissable warning and messager in Rmarkdwon notebook?

I am aware that each code chunk can look like this:

```
{r,  warning=F, message=F}
```

How ever I tried to create  markdown template that should do it:

````
---
title: "Data X"
subtitle: "R Notebook"
author: Petr Hrobar
output:
  html_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 8
    fig_width: 10
    highlight: pygments
    message: no
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    warnings: no
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
---


This is an [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) Notebook. When you execute code within the notebook, the results appear beneath the code. 

Try executing this chunk by clicking the *Run* button within the chunk or by placing your cursor inside it and pressing *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. 

Balicky z dnesni hodiny:
```{r}
library(tidyverse)
````

However this approach is not working for me I thought that including `warnings: no` in head of the template would help.

Comment: Hi,Try ```{r ,echo=FALSE}``` might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is:

````
```{r set knitr options, echo = FALSE}
# set some knitr options
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE
                      , message = FALSE
                      , warning = FALSE)
```
````

Other options to be set here can be found (e.g.) in this [cheat sheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiD9sr03qPnAhXMAxAIHQnAC1wQFjAAegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Frstudio.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F02%2Frmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2JPoZecb8BAHRdCxcP3wDE).